# Making a portable version of an Aperture Library

Tags: mac, aperture

I'm going on holiday.

I want to copy my aperture library to an external disk, work on my keywording while I'm gone, and copy the library back, when I get back. In principle I don't have to copy the images back, just the database with the new keywords.

Ideally I'd like to copy a reduces version of the images so my poor ancient laptop isn't struggling with a 280 GB library.

Is this possible?

Comment: The reduce quality part is going to be tricky, I suspect. Because you don't want to copy those same files back to your main library, so your computer would have to somehow keep track of which reduced quality image maps to which original image.

Comment: I don't think you old laptop would struggling with a large library. It might be slow to batch process. But it will display images using cached thumbnails, which is normally fast enough.